# Ubuntu server 16.04 execute rbenv commands on startup

Tags: server, bash, virtualbox

I installed an Ubuntu Server 16.04.1 on a VirtualBox 5.0.1

I followed the instructions to install ruby [here](https://gorails.com/deploy/ubuntu/16.04) and it worked

In the instructions there are these directives

```
echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc
echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> ~/.bashrc
exec $SHELL

echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc
exec $SHELL
```

What is happening is that every time I restart the VM, it seems that is not executing `~/.bashrc` because it cannot find ruby

I tried moving the `exports` and `eval` lines to `~/.profile` and `~/.bash_profile`

But it did not work

Comment: How are you testing whether it can find ruby?

Comment: In the terminal I am writing `ruby -v` it says that it is not installed, but if I execute `source ~/.bash` then it prints the version, thank you @chicks

Comment: What `PATH` do you get when you login?